# WCF error: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-8, wcf-binding

I created a WCF service to upload the 1MB file data into Windows Server. This web service is working fine with small file (950 KB) data but it has an issue with larger file size.

I tried several ways to fix it in WCF web.config but still stuck in above error. I need helps to setup on WCF configuration to resolve my issue.

Here are my web.config as following:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.UploadService">
        <endpoint address="REST" behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFServiceBinding" contract="WCFService.IUploadService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WCFServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="20971520" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Kindly correct above WCF web.config

Comment: Have you checked the `uploadReadAheadSize` in IIS

Comment: Yes already configured to uploadReadAheadSize = 8388608

Comment: I had this issue which was resolved by changing the value in Nginx. Not sure if you are using it but that was what solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks Usman, but I am not using Nginx. any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below configuration, it supports both Http and Https. You can cut it as needed. Besides, I use the ProtocolMapping feature to simplify my configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" name="httpbinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147473647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="httpsbinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147473647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <!--http and https are all supported.-->
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding"/>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="httpsbinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

For how to simplify the configuration,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/simplified-configuration
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.